# Is this Donald Trump and did he slap the governor of Mexico City?

Tags: donald-trump, violence

Someone sent me [a video](https://streamable.com/arp7x) that has been going around where Donald Trump allegedly slaps/fights the governor of Mexico City. I'm skeptical about such claim.

A quick search took me to [this website](https://hoax-alert.leadstories.com/3469076-fake-news-yves-merlette-rencontre-entre-trump-et-le-gouverneur-de-la-ville-de-mexico-envoye-par-un-a.html) which claims it is false. The website and contents looks legit, but who knows; spreading *fake news*™ on the web isn't complicated which is to say the website could be false as well.

I'm wondering

1. whether it is really Trump on the video, and
2. whether the contents are staged since the contents on the video look real (although I doubt that gentleman is/was the *governor of Mexico City*).

Comment: If you follow the wikipedia link on the second page you are linking, you can check that wikipedia offers a poster of the WrestleMania 23 event, where it can indeed be checked that it was Trump and the other man was Vince McMahon. Considering the event the shown events were extremely likely staged, although that cannot be proven with 100% security.

Comment: That's from Wrestlemania, and everything associated with that is staged.  In no way can it be said to reflect "real life".  (We won't go into whether the current occupants of the Swamp House reflect "real life".)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The image appears to be from Wrestlemania 23.  The gentleman(?) on the right is apparently WWE chairman Vince McMahon.

https://www.gettyimages.com/event/battle-of-the-billionaires-announce-details-of-wrestlemania-23-73703995#/donald-trump-wrestler-stone-cold-steve-austin-and-wwe-chairman-vince-picture-id73732795

This meeting is reported to have occurred at Trump Tower in March of 2007.  One presumes that, in keeping with WWE traditions, the thing was completely staged.

Comment: My next Skeptics.SE question: is wresting fake?

Comment: @user5341 -- Skeptics SE is for **notable** claims.

Comment: @user5341 Wrestlers are real performing artists staging wrestling matches.

Comment: is wrestling fake is a very notable claims. It's not fake. It's staged